# How do user agents distinguish domains from file extensions in relative urls?

Tags: html, url, user-agent

Let's say a browser encounters a link like this:

```
<a href='stackoverflowhome.html'>home</a>
```

This is clearly a relative url to an html file in the current directory, but how does the browser know that the .html is a file extension, and not a TLD (top level domain)? Does it have a list of common file extensions, or a list of TLDs? And if so, is it manually updated whenever a new file format becomes commonly used, or when the list of accepted TLDs change, for example with brand tlds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because that is how [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1) specified that URIs should be parsed.  If the URI does not have a `scheme` (a set of characters followed by a colon - e. g. `http:` or `gopher:`) then it must be treated as a relative URI.  Quoting from the RFC:

> A URI-reference is either a URI or a relative reference.  If the
> URI-reference's prefix does not match the syntax of a scheme followed
> by its colon separator, then the URI-reference is a relative
> reference.

User-agents are allowed to make their best guess about what the user meant (see [section 4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.5)) especially in cases where the context is ambiguous (such as URL bars in browsers) but the RFC recommends against it where the URI will be around for a long time as the best guess of user-agents will change over time, thus leading to URIs that don't resolve to the same resource depending on the time they are accessed or the user-agent they are accessed with.

Comment: That may be how the spec states it, but when I make a link such as `<a href='stackoverflow.com'>SO</a>` The browser will still send me to stack overflow, even though there's no scheme. Intelligently doing what the author of the document meant, instead of blindly following the spec.

Comment: @sys.stderr - when I try editing any of the links on this page (using Chrome's developer tools) `stackoverflow.com` is treated as a relative reference.  What browser are you using where you are seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs are never domain names.

A URL is only parsed as containing a domain name if it has a protocol. (or is protocol-relative).

Answer (score 0):

The URL does not start with a protocol specifier - no `http://`  or `https://`, so is interpreted as a relative URL.

Comment: Pedantic note: a URI that starts with `//` is still a relative URI according to [RFC 3986.4.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2)